# kvm qemu guest_agent issue on windows vm's

Tags: linux, virtualization, linux-kvm

i'm using kvm virtualazor
i have windows vm and i successfully installed the drivers and qemu-ga i do active the guest agent option in virtualazor but unfortunately its wont recognize the agent
inside the windows vm
 here's the ouput when i run qemu-ga.exe:

```
QEMU Guest Agent VSS Provider[1488]: DllMain begin, reason = 1
QEMU Guest Agent VSS Provider[1488]: DllMain end
QEMU Guest Agent VSS Provider[1488]: requester_init begin
QEMU Guest Agent VSS Provider[1488]: requester_init end
1698769110.306853: critical: error opening path \\.\Global\org.qemu.guest_agent.0: The system cannot find the file specified.
1698769110.323276: critical: error opening channel
1698769110.323276: critical: failed to create guest agent channel
1698769110.355665: critical: failed to initialize guest agent channel
QEMU Guest Agent VSS Provider[1488]: DllMain begin, reason = 0
QEMU Guest Agent VSS Provider[1488]: DllMain end
```

**on the newer windows versions like 2022 with latest updates i got access denied message in this output with same webdav error below this:**

```
QEMU Guest Agent VSS Provider[6652]: DllMain begin, reason = 1
QEMU Guest Agent VSS Provider[6652]: DllMain end
QEMU Guest Agent VSS Provider[6652]: requester_init begin
QEMU Guest Agent VSS Provider[6652]: requester_init end
1698758426.411241: critical: error opening path \\.\Global\org.qemu.guest_agent.0: Access is denied.
1698758426.444493: critical: error opening channel
1698758426.444493: critical: failed to create guest agent channel
1698758426.461036: critical: failed to initialize guest agent channel
QEMU Guest Agent VSS Provider[6652]: DllMain begin, reason = 0
QEMU Guest Agent VSS Provider[6652]: DllMain end
```

i do installed the spice guest tools and spice webdav 
but even the webdav service cannot start successfully(crash with code 1067):

```
** (spice-webdavd.exe:2188): ERROR **: 10:45:16.262: The service process could n
ot connect to the service controller.
```

there's no logs about guest agent in libvirt!
any help would be useful <3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it got solved when I used version `virtio-win-0.1.215` and stopped the VM, disabled `Qemu Guest Agent` in proxmox and then enabled it again. After starting the VM the guest agent was running fine.